# Which is equivalent to useEffect in class about React lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using slider component.

In my sample program. `Slider.create` is called in `useEffect()`

```
export default function SectionBasics() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (
      !document
        .getElementById("sliderRegular")
        .classList.contains("noUi-target")
    ) {
      Slider.create(document.getElementById("sliderRegular"), {
        start: [40],
        connect: [true, false],
        step: 1,
        range: { min: 0, max: 100 }
      });
    }
 });
 return (<div id=slider></div>)
}
```

However I want to move this to class extends React.Component

So, I can't use `useEffect()`, then I try put it in `render()`

```
class ParamBoard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (
      !document
        .getElementById("slider")
        .classList.contains("noUi-target")
    ) {
      Slider.create(document.getElementById("slider"), {
        start: [40],
        connect: [true, false],
        step: 1,
        range: { min: 0, max: 100 }
      });
    }
    return (<div id=slider></div>)
   }
```

I guess this is because when `render()` is called id `slider` is not ready yet.

However where should I put Slider.create in class??

Comment: `componentDidMount`? See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html, which has class-based equivalents for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a slider instance once when component mounts

In functional component, you can simply put it in `useEffect` hook with empty array dependency

This is equivalent to `componentDidMount()` in class component.

They run once when the component mounts.

```js
export default function SectionBasics() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // ... your code goes here
  }, []);
  return <div id="slider"></div>;
}

class ParamBoard extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // ... your code goes here
  }
  render() {
    return <div id="slider"></div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this is similar to normal class structure of other language. IT is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could pass a function to `ref` which will be called as soon as the dom-node exists (or changes)

```
class ParamBoard extends React.Component {
  initSlider = node => {
    Slider.create(node, {
      start: [40],
      connect: [true, false],
      step: 1,
      range: { min: 0, max: 100 }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (<div ref={this.initSlider}></div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: I see . thank you very much It is also great hint.